# Mature bluetooth stack for embedded systems?

Tags: bluetooth, embedded

I'd like suggestions for a mature bluetooth stack to use on an embedded system.
It's imperative that it's lightweight and with a relatively low footprint.

Preferably it is also open source, has support for BLE and can run without an OS. But those are not strictly required.

It doesn't necessarily have to be free. It will also be used commercially.

I'm running a STM32 processor (ARM), which it should either directly support or be general enough that it would be easy to port it.

Kind regards

Comment: Unfortunately, there aren't any free open source options.  There are a few companies that sell/license such embedded stacks.

Comment: The company I work for has a bluetooth stack that meets your requirements (not free though). http://www.stollmann.de/en/stacks/bluetooth-bluetooth-low-energy.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Bluetooth Chip or Module are you using?

You may find that the chip manufacturer can provide you with a embedded BT stack.

For example, CSR (Cambridge Silicon Radio), purveyors of fine Bluetooth 4.0 chips, have a product called Synergy, which is a BT stack for embedded devices. There is an Android and a WinCE version but there is also a core version, which has and can be ported to many different OS and HW platforms.

www.csrsupport.com

I think Broadcom make BT chips too.

Comment: Synergy supports BLE but is not open source.

Comment: My manufacturer(STericsson) can unfortunately not provide a bluetooth stack. I'm using a CG2900, http://www.stericsson.com/products/cg2900-gps.jsp .

Answer (score 3):

Apache now has an open source BLE stack called [NimBLE](http://mynewt.apache.org/network/ble/ble_intro/) that runs on its [MyNewt](http://mynewt.apache.org/) OS. It runs on nRF5x chips and is the only vaguely complete open source BLE stack. I haven't tried it yet but it looks pretty good.

Edit: I've tried it. As of now (September 2016), it does work - you can read/write/notify characteristics and so on. There are some missing features, but it is definitely usable.

Be warned, the code is quite well written (e.g. they've even documented which functions run in interrupt contexts!) but it is classic C89, so there is lots of manual memory management, worrying pointer magic, trusting array lengths and so on. There's also no support for C++ in their `newt` build system.

Answer (score 1):

You might take a look at Smalltooth.  It targets PIC24 and PIC32, but might be adaptable to ARM.
[SmallTooth Bluetooth Stack](http://code.google.com/p/smalltooth/) is an open source Bluetooth stack coded from scratch with an embedded device in mind.

Comment: The only drawback there is that it's limited to BT Classic and it's server only for only a few profiles.  It makes for a nice enough stack if you're using a *REALLY* resource constrained device (It was designed with PICs in mind...) and you're within the domain that it covers.  No LE though.  No clients though.  If you want/need a device to be the Central in the relationship, you're SOL with this stack

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at our BTstack Bluetooth Stack at http://bluekitchen-gmbh.com

It seems to meet all your requirements.

Comment: The questioner asked for an OPEN SOURCE stack.  Yours is a source-provided one, but requires money royalties to be paid for use in commercial projects.  Doesn't QUITE meet the questioner's request, does it?

Comment: I understand that his/her focus was on lightweight and low footprint. Open source and/or free to use commercially was listed as 'nice to have'.